# Angularjs analogue of jQuery .always()

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a HTTP request to my server and can't find the answer on my question how to make `.always()` like in jQuery style.

According Angular's documentation of `$http`, there is only this construction:

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: `$http.get(...).finally(function(){...});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the `finally()`:

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
  then(function(response) {
   // this callback will be called asynchronously
   // when the response is available
  }.catch(error) {
   // called asynchronously if an error occurs
   // or server returns response with an error status.
  }).finally() {
    //Always do something
  });
```

Which will always be called no matter what the outcome is.

You can read about this in the documentation for `$q` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: but why there is no information on Angular's website?